# Minutes not converting to hours properly in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, time

I am trying to convert minuts to hours, but it is doing some weird rounding on me when I /60. My code is

```
select 

pct.patient_id,
pct.attending_id,
pct.clinic_id,
pct.service_id,
pct.program_id,
pct.protocol_id,
pct.proc_code,
pct.proc_chron,
pct.proc_duration--/60


from patient_clin_tran pct
join patient p
on pct.patient_id = p.patient_id and pct.episode_id = p.episode_id
join staff s
on pct.attending_id = s.staff_id
where (pct.proc_chron between '2014-04-01' and '2014-06-01') and pct.proc_code = 'BHH'

order by patient_id, pct.proc_chron asc
```

and my results without the /60 are

[image]

With the /60
[image]

I'm assuming their is something more needed for it not to do whatever rounding it is doing. Thank you in advance. I am using SQL Server 2005

Comment: You don't say what you want.  The values look correct to me.  Remember that SQL Server does integer division.  So, if you want decimals use `/60.0` or `/cast(60 as float)` for the division.

Comment: The /cast(60 as float) is what I needed. Thank you.